# running a command when a button is pressed on a raspberry pi not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio

I thought i had it correct but i must be doing something wrong.

What i want to happen is when i press the button the first time its sets the override_set to true and then runs the command for the stepper motor and then prints on the screen that the override is enabled. when you press the button again it runs the stepper motor in forward and then sets the override_set to false.

https://paste.pythondiscord.com/rivaxepoxa.py

```py
override_set = False

#setting button stuff up
def override (channel):
    global override_set
    global kit
    global gate_open
    override_set = not override_set
    if overide_set == True:
            cv2.putText(frame,'Overide Enabled',(int(IM_WIDTH*.1),int(IM_HEIGHT*.5)),font,3,(0,0,0),7,cv2.LINE_AA)
    if override_set:
        for i in range(200):
            kit.stepper1.onestep(direction=stepper.BACKWARD,style=stepper.MICROSTEP)
        gate_open = True
    else:
        for i in range(200):
                kit.stepper1.onestep(direction=stepper.FORWARD,style=stepper.MICROSTEP)
        gate_open = False
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.FALLING, callback=override, bouncetime=300)


  [1]: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/rivaxepoxa.py
```

Comment: this is my first post im not sure how to format the code correctly

Comment: What does the code currently do? Note: you never unset the override enabled text

Comment: well nothing when i press the button nothing happens but it doesn't crash anymore so thats a plus.

Comment: I could post the whole code if needed but its over 300 lines. This is towards the top. Ultimately i would like this part if set to true then for it to keep restarting this part of the code and then move on to the next section of code

Comment: i think im problem is the callback i dont know if im using it correctly or if i have it defined right

Comment: the full code is here https://paste.pythondiscord.com/rivaxepoxa.py

Comment: What you have looks fine. Have you tried just defining a function that prints things or counts how many times you've clicked? That would help you debug if you've defined things correctly